# Event Reciever run with elevated previledges

Tags: list, visual-studio, event-receivers, runwithelevatedprivileges

I created one event receiver and deployed it, but only users who are site collection admins are able to view this web part. I have included the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges but the same thing. What am I missing?

Below is my code

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
       {SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
        string name= web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["first name"].InternalName; 
        var list = web.Lists["location names"]; 
  });}
```

Comment: While not necessarily causing this behavior, do you need those two "base.ItemAdding(properties);" rows?

Comment: What do you mean "view this webpart"? Does the code not work for non-site admins?

Comment: @tarjeieo ..yes the non site admins were getting access denied

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should recreate context.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
   using(SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
   {
      using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
      {
          //code
      }
   }   
});
```

Comment: @FreeStyler, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant is whenever we use 'RunWithElevatedPrviliges', we have to take the current context outside the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block and then create a new instance of SPSite and SPWeb inside the that block which will run under application pool identity. The code above is exactly doing so!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your solution is a farm solution, not a sandbox solution.