# Event Receiver How to change account of Firing Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers, user-accounts

Event receiver always running on privilages of acount who logged in. How to change in Event Receiver Account with who is firing the account. How could I set a account for firing event receiver ? By the code. Please help.

**UPDATE**

I have got code, and it give me error:

unauthorizedaccessexception was unhandled by user code But i Tried to put a user with previlages:

```
        public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                            string Tytuł = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                            string UnikalnaNazwa = properties.ListItem["UnikalnaNazwa"].ToString();
                            string fieldB = properties.ListItem["B"].ToString();
                            string fieldStatus = properties.ListItem["Status"].ToString();

                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UnikalnaNazwa'/><Value Type='Text'>" + UnikalnaNazwa + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                            SPListItemCollection items = lstOtherList.GetItems(query);
                            SPListItem item = items[0];

                            item["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                            item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                            item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                            item.Update();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];

                            string Tytuł = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                            string UnikalnaNazwa = properties.ListItem["UnikalnaNazwa"].ToString();
                            string fieldB = properties.ListItem["B"].ToString();
                            string fieldStatus = properties.ListItem["Status"].ToString();

                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UnikalnaNazwa'/><Value Type='Text'>" + UnikalnaNazwa + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                            SPListItemCollection items = lstOtherList.GetItems(query);
                            SPListItem item = items[0];

                            item["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                            item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                            item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                            item.Update();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried it to, but still geting this error:

```
        public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);
            if (properties.List.Title == "Jawna")
            {
                                            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                                            {
                                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                                    {
                                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                                        {
                                                SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Niejawna"];
                                                string Tytuł = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                                                string UnikalnaNazwa = properties.ListItem["UnikalnaNazwa"].ToString();
                                                string fieldB = properties.ListItem["B"].ToString();
                                                string fieldStatus = properties.ListItem["Status"].ToString();

                                                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UnikalnaNazwa'/><Value Type='Text'>" + UnikalnaNazwa + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                                                SPListItemCollection items = lstOtherList.GetItems(query);
                                                SPListItem item = items[0];

                                                item["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                                                item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                                                item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                                                item.Update();

                                        }
                                    }
                        });
            }
            if (properties.List.Title == "Niejawna")
            {
                                            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.WebUrl))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                                {

                                        SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];

                                        string Tytuł = properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString();
                                        string UnikalnaNazwa = properties.ListItem["UnikalnaNazwa"].ToString();
                                        string fieldB = properties.ListItem["B"].ToString();
                                        string fieldStatus = properties.ListItem["Status"].ToString();

                                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UnikalnaNazwa'/><Value Type='Text'>" + UnikalnaNazwa + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                                        SPListItemCollection items = lstOtherList.GetItems(query);
                                        SPListItem item = items[0];

                                        item["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
                                        item["B"] = properties.AfterProperties["B"];
                                        item["Status"] = properties.AfterProperties["Status"];
                                        item.Update();

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: ECM4D's answer is correct. Note that answer is creating new spweb and spsite objects inside the runWithElevatedPrivileges block. In your code above, you are using the existing spweb object that was outside of the block.

Comment: I tried it too but still getting this error. I updated my Question. Look on update 2

Comment: You created a new spweb object, but then you didn't use it. You're using properties.Web, which was passed in via the parameter and was not created in the elevated block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can impersonate in the event receiver. Usually, running code under System User is required and it is done using throuth `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` method, like:

```
Guid siteGuid = properties.SiteId;
Guid webGuid = properties.Web.ID;
Guid listGuid = properties.ListId;
int listItemId = properties.ListItemId;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite elevSite = new SPSite(siteGuid))
    using (SPWeb elevWeb = elevSite.OpenWeb(webGuid))
    {

        SPList elevList= elevWeb.Lists[listGuid];
        SPListItem elevListItem= elevList.GetItemById(listItemId);

        // Your code
    }
}
```

You can look also: [Event Reciever run with elevated previledges](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27545/event-reciever-run-with-elevated-previledges)

If you need really impersonate another specific user, you should use impersonation functionality. Here is some useful links:

1. https://anujpant.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/sharepoint-user-impersonation-with-spusertoken/
2. http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/

Comment: So only I should do it by: SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{

Comment: Yeh, it is the most common way to impersonate to user with higher permissions. On the other hand, I added another link how to impersonate with another specific user.

Comment: After I add delegate, I'm getting this exception: unauthorizedaccessexception was unhandled by user code

Comment: Please, ensure that you reinitialize SPSite and SPWeb object inside delegate, as showed in my example. Maybe you could share some code?

Comment: I updated my Question with code on Update. And Error shows me on item.Update();

Comment: You have to reinitiate SPWeb and SPSite objects INSIDE delegate

Comment: I tried it too but still getting this error. I updated my Question.

Comment: You have to use your elevated SPSite and SPWeb objects inside you delegate. Example, do not use `properties.Web.Lists["Jawna"];` , use `web.Lists["Jawna"];`

Comment: Now works great. Thanks ECM4D. Why I must change it ? To reinitiate ?

Comment: When you are inside event receiver your SPWeb object is in the same context of current user. When you impersonate a user (using RunWithElevated delegate), you have take new SPWeb object that is with higher permissions and use it