# Breaking Item Item level permission under SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers

In my event receiver, I am trying to break item permission. Following is my code.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    if (properties.List.Title == "Validation Draft") {
        if (properties.AfterProperties["Status"].ToString() == "APP") {
            using(var spSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId)) {
                using(var spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb()) {
                    var item = properties.ListItem;
                    if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                        item.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
                    }

                    var validationMemberGroup = spWeb.Groups.GetByName("Aurora Validation Members");
                    var validationReviewerGroup = spWeb.Groups.GetByName("Aurora Validation Reviewer");
                    var validationApproverGroup = spWeb.Groups.GetByName("Aurora Validation Approver");

                    var assignedTo = new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, item["Assigned_x0020_To0"].ToString());

                    SPRoleDefinition roleDefintion = spWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);

                    // read permission to assignedTo
                    SPRoleAssignment assignedToRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(assignedTo.User);
                    assignedToRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefintion);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(assignedToRoleAssignment);

                    // read permission to Validation Members
                    SPRoleAssignment validationMemberGroupRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(validationMemberGroup);
                    validationMemberGroupRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefintion);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(validationMemberGroupRoleAssignment);

                    // read permission to Validation Reviewer
                    SPRoleAssignment validationReviewerGroupRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(validationReviewerGroup);
                    validationReviewerGroupRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefintion);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(validationReviewerGroupRoleAssignment);

                    // read permission to Validation Approver
                    SPRoleAssignment validationApproverGroupRoleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(validationApproverGroup);
                    validationApproverGroupRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefintion);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(validationApproverGroupRoleAssignment);
                    item.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it works for site admins only but not for the other users.

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27545/event-reciever-run-with-elevated-previledges

Comment: Thanks @AsadRefai. I saw that already and recreated context. It did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no point in opening an elevated section and a new `SPWeb` object under it if finally you use the initial (non-elevated) `properties.ListItem` object. `properties.ListItem` won't be elevated even if used inside `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. You need to retrieve a new reference to the item *from the elevated `SPWeb`* (i.e. your `spWeb`):

   ```
   var list = spWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];  
   var item = list.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);
   ```
2. `item.Update();` is not needed here: `.Update` is required when you change values, not when dealing with permissions.

Comment: Absolutely!!!   I have fixed that already after reading this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sasohail/archive/2010/10/31/access-denied-within-spsecurity-runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx. I did not have enough idea about elevated privilege. Thank u